# routing and clean path (no hashtag) not working in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat

Guys this is driving me crazy, been fighting for hours on this, and couldn't find a solution!

I know that in order to clean the hashtag from the URL path, i need to use the

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

But for some reason this is not working well for me, I'm using tomcat 7 btw to run this.

These are my HTML imports, both AngularJS stuff are v1.2.6:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- Angular Libraries -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- This one handles the alert notifications -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-flash.min.js"></script>

    <!-- App related libraries -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/portfolioServices.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/myWorkControllers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/navController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/aboutController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/contactController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives/portfolioDirectives.js"></script>
```

Then this is my Service javascript with the config

```
portfolioApp = angular.module('portfolioApp', ['ngRoute']);

portfolioApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/mywork', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/mywork.htm',
            controller: 'myWorkController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/about.htm',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/contact.htm',
            controller: 'contactController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/mywork'});    
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Each of those controllers is only defined, nothing special, the name and the function injecting the $scope. Nothing in them.

Basically, the URL without using the html5Mode is

```
http://localhost:8080/template/#/
```

I would like to be:

```
http://localhost:8080/mywork
http://localhost:8080/about
http://localhost:8080/contact
```

Now, i could make it work... by accessing to `http://localhost:8080/template` it gets redirected to those url's above... but when i refresh the page with Ctrl+F5, i get a 404 Not Found from Tomcat! :S how come?? the path shouldn't be solved by angular?

Please what am I doing wrong in here? I'm really getting mad hahah

Btw, just in case you want to know how my project directory is, here's a screeshot of it:

http://puu.sh/5UI0Z.png

This is my current web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Portfolio Application</display-name>

    <!-- Auto scan rest service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit F5, you're not using an angular directive or anything angular-related. You simply tell the browser to send a new request to the URL that is currently in the address bar, and to refresh the page with what comes back from the server. So if the current location is `http://localhost:8080/mywork`, a request will be sent to `http://localhost:8080/mywork`, and if the server doesn't have anything configured to handle this URL, you'll get a 404.

Now, if you configure the server to return the main angular HTML page when the URL `/mywork` is hit, then the browser will display this HTML page and execute the JavaScript it contains. The angular router will detect that the location is /mywork, and it will thus load the partial and the controller associated with this location, and display the appropriate template.

The old, hashbang-based routing doesn't need any configuration of the backend because the URL is always the same. Only the part after the hashbang (unknown by the server), changes.

Comment: Mmmm interesting, didn't think about that. Would it be a problem in the web.xml path? could i fix this from there?

Comment: You can indeed map a servlet forwarding to the HTML in web.xml, and map this servlet to all your bookmarkable URLs.

Comment: i've added my web.xml, i got a restful service also on this app that i want to consume. Could you tell me how should i need to change the web.xml to forward to the corresponding urls? :(

Comment: Make a break, go to sleep, and then google for "servlet tutorial" to know how to declare and map a servlet. Then do the same with "how to forward from a servlet to an HTML page" to understand how to implement the servlet.

Comment: hahaha my brain is about to collapse :( ok, thanks for the adv JB. I will go to sleep now haha

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried myself yet, but from what I know, you have to make sure that your server simply returns your initial HTML page for these non-existing URLs. Then when the page will reload, an `onload` event will be fired and you can access the last state via `history.state`. I guess angular will just restore the state automatically so you shouldn't have to worry about this.

Comment: So you say that i shouldn't worry about this for now? if i access to portfolio, i get into the page, when then i try to browse through the sections of mywork, about and contact, the URL changes (removes the porfolio/ part), the views works great... but as i told you, if i refresh, i get the 404 error.

Comment: @user3078876: plalx is telling you the same thing as I am: "you have to make sure that your server simply returns your initial HTML page for these non-existing URLs".

Comment: yea :( gonna see how to fix it, added the web.xml in the post, tho. 6am here still awake haha

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by adding a  in web.xml

When you refresh the target page manually,  will redirect the 404page to your main page. And then angular router will take in effect to route this to target page.