# could refresh page without hashtag and be in same page? Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want reload my view from navigation bar and this show me the browser server...
I have the html5Mode activated:

```
          if(window.history && window.history.pushState) {
              $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
          }
```

Exameple:

-I load http://localhost/myBase/

-when I click in link, I load the view and show this url in navigation bar http://localhost/myBase/page1

-then, I refresh the page and as I don't have a hashtag in the url, In navigator show the server folder...

could refresh page without hashtag and be in same page?

Comment: i wantt help you but in this way you give too few informations. First of all what library do you use for the view? ng-view? and second can you write the code of the link?

Comment: when I load a page from navigation bar as I haven't a hashtag in url and page not load.
I use a "<div ng-view></div>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a complex solution to your problem: if you can access to apache configuration, and apache has enabled de rewrite module, you can make a rule to rewrite the url in case of this not contains the hashtag.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /yourBaseUrl
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^#]+)$ #/$1 [NE,R]
```

Putting the previous code in your *.htaccess* file or in your *virtualhost* configuration you can solve your problem. But be carefully modificating this, you can broke the entire web server.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because a refresh is a browser thing. It's beyond the scope of javascript. The browser will send out a request to the server and render the page again which will angular bootstrap again and your application will get an initial state.

Have a look at this: [routing and clean path (no hashtag) not working in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727602/routing-and-clean-path-no-hashtag-not-working-in-angularjs)

Comment: there is a way using angular ui route, you can handle the address in the naviagtion bar, without i believe that you are not using it, let check the documentation.

Comment: I want hit F5 and be in same page... but i don't know if is possible

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose i often use two between these solutions,
1) I use angular-ui rather then ng-view, it uses states rather then address, and it handles the addresses in the navigation bar in a way that you could not consider the '#', in fact the ui-router module when 'receives' an address, knows the view that it has to use.
2)the second way it's a little bit less elegant, you could put a script in the main page like:

```
function foo('somewhere'){
    window.onload=function(){
        $location.path(somewhere)
    }
}
```

I had use that solution once, because i already had a big application and i didn't want to substitute ng-view, but since that time i always use ui-router, in somewhere you put a global variable that refer to the actual page.